# Does the C language require short circuit/minimal evaluation of logical statements?

Tags: c, short-circuiting

The GCC specification states that logical statements are short circuited: [Logical Operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Logical-Operators)

Is this something specific to the GCC implementation or is short circuit logical evaluation inherently in C? Could I rely on this behavior without needing to worry about which compiler might eventually be used on my code?